# How to detect the classic crash test dummy fiducial marker in real time?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, fiducial-markers

I'm referring to the markers that look like this:
[image: crash test dummy fiducial marker]

I believe that some combination of Harris corner detection plus a Hough transform to get the lines of interest could be used to locate the marker. It would be ideal to locate the marker plus get the bounds of it (as an ellipse) or the orientation of it (as a cylinder/tangent vector).

There must be a paper on this but I am having trouble finding one.

Comment: This is a solid use case for deep learning object detection too. If you have a couple of photos you could label them yourself and then finetune a custom detector to draw a bounding box around the symbol. You can find more [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_pets.md) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection)